# Debug and lookup emulated x86_64 registers on apple silicon?

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb, x86-64, apple-silicon

I currently use a M1 MacBook Air. I want to debug C code, but with x86_64 assembly syntax and registers, on my local computer.

I tried installing `gdb`, but it was complicated to setup on my machine. I also tried `UTM emulation`, `qemu`, they returned `error` about some non privileged actions related to gdb or debugging itself.

I know there are online free solutions (https://www.onlinegdb.com/). But there is satisfaction doing it on local machine. After a few days of reading docs and tinkering I found an acceptable solution using `lldb`.  Also, onlinegdb is Linux, not macOS.  And only GAS, not other assemblers like NASM.

See below for the Solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a File.

```
❯ vim main.c
```

Compile it to binary (-arch x86_64). See ([How can I create a x86_64 assembly file from C source code in apple silicon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75835866/how-can-i-create-a-x86-64-assembly-file-from-c-source-code-in-apple-silicon)).

```
❯ clang -g -O0 -Wall -arch x86_64 -o main main.c
```

[ Optional One Time Setup ]:  Use this command to view debug assembly code with intel syntax. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21502943/14668175)

```
❯ echo "settings set target.x86-disassembly-flavor intel" >> ~/.lldbinit
```

Use lldb to debug. lldb commands (https://lldb.llvm.org/use/map.html).

```
❯ lldb -arch x86_64 main
```

You are all set.